# Removing lines with more than X characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to clean a text, what's the right regular expression in ***Notepad++*** to remove lines which are more than 5 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, activate RegEx (bottom left), search for

`^{6,}`

and replace with nothing (leave field empty).

If your lines start with whitespaces (spaces, tabs, ..) i'd recommend to clean them up first. For that, open the Search&Replace window again, search for `^\s+`, replace with nothing and hit "Replace all". After that, try the trick above.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ press CTRL+H, activate RegEx (bottom left), search for

^.{6,}